# how add php support to my nodejs webserver

Tags: php, node.js, webserver

I have created http/https web-server using NodeJS, support all static files but I want add support for PHP dynamic files (like Nginx + php fpm)

I need use exec(); for execute php.exe and get result in stdout ? Or php-fpm..

Thanks for your help

(Sorry for my bad english I'm french)

Answer (score 0):

you should work with `child_process` module of node.js core, and spawn commands for each call you want make, more documentation here [child_process](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) .

Comment: Yes but I need use php-cgi/fpm for make real support of php